# GitHub flow: how do I test my changes that cannot be tested locally?

Tags: git, github, continuous-delivery

I am trying to start using GitHub flow in my project. I like that it is simple and, more importantly, it encourages continuous delivery.

However, there is one thing about this flow that I cannot understand: *how do I test my changes?* The 5th step of [the official guide](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) says:

> Once your pull request has been reviewed and the branch passes your tests, you can deploy your changes to verify them in production.

But what if these "my tests" (or at least some of them) cannot be run locally, what if in order to run the tests I have to deploy my changes to a TEST environment first? What branch do I deploy then?

Now, I could deploy my `feature` branch to TEST. But what if other developers also want to deploy their feature branches at the same time? They will then inevitably rewrite my changes. The solution to this could be having many TEST environments, but again, this can be too expensive and, moreover, this approach still allows to only test the features in isolation. If two features work in isolation, it does not yet mean, that they will work together (once deployed to production).

Another option would be to have a dedicated branch for deploying to TEST environment, say `next`. I could merge my feature branch to `next` and then deploy `next` to TEST. But then why does GitHub flow say nothing about it? By the way, GitHub flow with `next` branch looks very much like [Gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) already.

To summarize my question: how do I test my changes that cannot be tested locally with GitHub flow? I really cannot believe that GitHub flow encourages me to do it in production.

Thank you.

Comment: This particular branching model doesn't appear to have what you need.  Perhaps you can evaluate Gitflow, described [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) and [here](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: You can also pick and choose what branching features you want.  For example, Gitflow includes in its model a provision for hot-fixing, but you won't need that if you never hot-fix.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, GitFlow is what is currently being used in my project. The problem with GitFlow is that you cannot really do continuous delivery with it, can you? I wonder, how can then GitHub flow be useful at all, if the only place to test my changes is my local environment?

Comment: As I understand it, your "continuous delivery" process is triggered by a merge to the Release branch.  At least, that's how it works where I work.

Comment: What prevents you from simply modifying one of these processes so that it does what you need it to do?

Comment: I agree that merging to release branch may be called "continues delivery", but not fully: I still have to wait once the release branch goes to production, and with GitFlow it is usually done according to a schedule, e.g., once per two weeks. I.e., even if my feature is ready and tested, I cannot deploy it to production when I want.
I think I am going to modify GitHub flow indeed by introducing `next` branch to it. Just wondering why GitHub flow does not include this modification by default.

Comment: Because everyone's needs are different.  For example, some shops deploy on a schedule, but other shops deploy when "feature complete" status is achieved.